# Headlines with "children" initial visibility reveals drawer names--why?

Tags: org-mode, visibility

I would like to see all first-level children of my level 1 headlines when I open an `org-mode` file. I have assigned property values of `:VISIBILITY: children` to all my level 1 headlines. When I open the file, why are the `:PROPERTIES:` and other drawer name lines visible as well? When I use the command `show-children` on a folded headline, I get the results I'm looking for (i.e., children visible and drawer names hidden). What is going on, and how can I hide the drawer names on startup (initial visibility)?

Comment: Can you give a receipt starting from `emacs -q`?

Comment: @rasmus, could you elaborate on what information you would like? Let me know if my question's not clear--I'll be happy to try to clarify.

Comment: since this is a potential bug report, I just want the exact steps I need to perform from  a clean emacs to see the issue you are describing.

Comment: Starting emacs without init files, create a new `org-mode` file. Create a level 1 heading. Create a level 2, subheading. Assign property `VISIBILITY` to level 1 heading (`C-c C-x p`) with a value of `children`. Cycle visibility of level 1 heading to folded. Running `show-children` (`C-c Tab`) on level 1 heading produces desired effect. However, running startup visibility (`C-u C-u Tab`) shows children *and* the line `:PROPERTIES:`--this is not the desired effect. Why are drawer names considered children now but not with the `show-children` function?